# Laravel API, MySQL Query, Get average data in same date

Tags: mysql, json, laravel, request, response

My table is about weight. For example,

```
(February 10, 2020) = 60kg
(February 11, 2020) = 62kg
(February 11, 2020) = 63kg
(February 11, 2020) = 64kg
(February 12, 2020) = 65kg
```

Json should return,

```
{
"weight": 60,
 "created_at": "2020-02-10"
},
{
"weight": 63,
"created_at": "2020-02-11"
},
{
"weight": 65,
"created_at": "2020-02-12"
}
```

with pagination.

Here's my existing code without average.

```
public function weightChart(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $data = WeightHistory::where('user_id', $id)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(7);


        return WeightChartResource::collection($data);
    }
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Why should `2020-02-12` return 64, not 65? Anything special we don't know about or just a typo?

Comment: its 65. I'm sorry.

Comment: @jaysamluligon I have added the answer. Please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Change your query

```
$data = WeightHistory::where('user_id', $id)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(7);
```

> To

```
$data = WeightHistory::where('user_id', $id)->select('created_at', DB::raw('AVG(weight) as weight'))->groupBy('created_at')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(7);
```

Comment: @jaysamluligon Welcome.. Keep learning. don't forget to upvote the answer. :)